# keras transferlearning predict classes working and predict not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am using transfer learning and building on top of the "inception_v3" model. Training seems to go well, i get a val_accuracy of 0.9526. I can also do predict_class after to get the predicted label for new samples - that also seems quite good. 
However, for some reason when i try to use the predict function, it always outputs very low probabilities in the range from 0 to 3.31e-11. I thought it should output probabilities in the range from 0 to 1?
Maybe I am doing something wrong? It's a 2-class problem, and this is what I am doing:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

image_size = (128,128)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    label_mode = 'binary',
    seed = 1337,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    label_mode = 'binary',
    seed = 1337,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)


global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
Dl_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.2)
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid') # 120, softmax

#Add dropout Layer
model_V3 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  pre_trained_model,
  global_average_layer,
  Dl_1,
  prediction_layer
])

model_V3.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',#sparse_categorical_crossentropy
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_V3.summary()

# Callbacks

lr_reduce = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=3, verbose=2, mode='max')
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.1, patience=1, mode='min')

hist = model_V3.fit(
           augmented_train_ds.repeat(), steps_per_epoch=int(8000/batch_size), 
           epochs=10, validation_data=augmented_val_ds.repeat(), 
           validation_steps=int(2000/batch_size) , callbacks=[lr_reduce])


Ypred = model_V3.predict(val_ds)  # <--- This always returns very low probabilities. Why?
```

Comment: What's the results while training?

Comment: Epoch 10/10
250/250 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1333 - accuracy: 0.9537
Epoch 00010: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 8.000000525498762e-06.
250/250 [==============================] - 20s 80ms/step - loss: 0.1333 - accuracy: 0.9537 - val_loss: 0.1389 - val_accuracy: 0.9506

Comment: The accuracy looks OK. What exactly predictions do you get?

Comment: I would expect probabilities in the interval [0,1] instead of in the interval [0,3.31e-11]

Comment: Is your dataset balanced? I mean the number of samples of 0 class nearly equal to the number of samples of 1 class?

Comment: its not super balanced. Its pretty much a 4:1 ratio in both the training and the validation set

Comment: As you can see here, i am only predicting the negative class for some reason: https://dpaste.org/rFoi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214309/discussion-between-yoskutik-and-michael-hansen).

Answer (score 0):

After help from Yoskutik the code now looks like the following and has improved, but I still don't understand why I get the results that I do (see code below).

In the final epoch i get this output

```
Epoch 5/5
414/414 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1207 - accuracy: 0.9587
Epoch 00005: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.00020000000949949026.
414/414 [==============================] - 98s 236ms/step - loss: 0.1207 - accuracy: 0.9587 - val_loss: 0.1029 - val_accuracy: 0.9661
```

So val_accuracy: 0.9661. But the calculated roc_auc_score shows 0.5150403105096363
and the confusion matrix shows:

```
[[2094  552]
 [ 545  114]]
```

How can a model with 96% accuracy give so poor results?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix,roc_auc_score

data_dir = '/path/to_dir/'

image_size = (128,128)
target_size = (128,128)
batch_size = 32

datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    zoom_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    rotation_range=10,
    rescale=1/255,
    validation_split=0.2,
    # other things...
)

train_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    subset="training",
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

val_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    subset="validation",
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)



pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape=(128,128,3),
                                include_top=False,
                                weights='imagenet')

for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False


global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
Dl_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.2)
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')

model_V3 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  pre_trained_model,
  global_average_layer,
  Dl_1,
  prediction_layer
])

model_V3.compile(optimizer='adam',
                 loss='binary_crossentropy',
                 metrics=['accuracy'])

lr_reduce = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=3, verbose=2, mode='max')

hist = model_V3.fit(
    train_ds, 
    epochs=5,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_ds), 
    validation_data=val_ds, 
    validation_steps=len(val_ds), 
    callbacks=[lr_reduce])

y_score = model_V3.predict(val_ds)
y_pclass = model_V3.predict_classes(val_ds)
print(confusion_matrix(val_ds.classes,y_pclass))
print(roc_auc_score(val_ds.classes, y_score))
```